# reading from excel file pandas in the desired type

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading excel file using pandas containing 2 columns:
df

```
EID      List of Tuples
 1       [('Physics', 90)]
 2       [('Physics', 80), ('Math', 70)]
 3       [('Physics', 60, ('Math', 25))]
```

when I check `df['List of Tuples'].iat[0]` it gives me `u"[('Physics', 90)]"`
I am getting this as a unicode and not as a list of tuples.
When I `df['List of Tuples'].iat[0].decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')`, I get `string: "[('Physics', 90)]"`
I want to read/convert it as list of tuples `[('Physics', 90)]` instead of string or unicode.In short,I want to get rid of  double quotes around each entry and read it as `[('Physics', 90)]` and  `[('Physics', 80), ('Math', 70)]` and so on.

Comment: The formatting is all over the place and I can't fix from my phone, but if you're hoping to use dataframes for lists of tuples in single cells, you're opening a door to a lot of pain. That's not how pandas works. You should shoot for a structure that has scalars in cells or, IMO, drop pandas if you can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find it useful to parse these into python objects using `ast` which can convert string representations back into python objectd. Try something like the following (I can't replicate exactly because I don't have your data):

```
import ast
df['transformed_tuples'] = df['List of Tuples'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

To avoid this arising in the first place you might consider the file format you choose to read/write to, for example pickle will retain the original information (I'm assuming this has come from a pandas DataFrame that has been saved to excel).

You might also consider a tabular schema which doesn't have this irregular data type within it which would probably prove to be more stable and effective in the long run.